# Hibernate POJO with two foreign keys from same table

Tags: hibernate, pojo

How do I create a POJO WITH ANNOTATIONS so that hibernate will create the table below upon mapping? one column is follow`EE` and one is follow`ER`.

```
CREATE TABLE friends(
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  followee_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  follower_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  start_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  end_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  KEY idx_fk_friends_followee_id (followee_id),
  KEY idx_fk_friends_follower_id (follower_id),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_friends_followee_id` FOREIGN KEY (followee_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_friends_follower_id` FOREIGN KEY (follower_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is your problem, as that is quite straight-forward I think:

```
@Entity
public class Friend {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private User follower;

  @ManyToOne
  private User followee;
}
```